# Can we use purrr::map() to *in-place* modify strings in nested structures?

Tags: r, purrr, tibble

I have a tibble that nests named lists. I want to apply a cleanup function (e.g., `janitor::make_clean_names()`) over the named lists: both the names *and* the values. Based on my basic understanding of `purrr` package, I think that `map()` is appropriate for such a task.

However, I don't know how to perform such a cleanup *in-place*, similar to the functionality of `dplyr`'s `mutate(across(...))`.

### Example

Here's a tibble for example:

```r
library(tibble)

my_tibble <-
  tibble(
  name = c("economics", "history","psychology", "biology"),
  info = list(
    list(
      GDP = "Gross domestic product",
      GNI = "Gross national income"
    ),
    NULL,
    list(
      Gestalt = "theory of perception",
      `Affective neuroscience` = "Study of the neural mechanisms of emotion",
      `Personality` = "personality and its variation among individuals"
    ),
    list(Photosynthesis = "convert light energy into chemical energy")
  )
)

my_tibble
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   name       info            
#>   <chr>      <list>          
#> 1 economics  <named list [2]>
#> 2 history    <NULL>          
#> 3 psychology <named list [3]>
#> 4 biology    <named list [1]>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

When we look at the `info` list-column, we see that it nests 4 lists (one is null), and those lists are *named*.

```r
library(dplyr)

pull(my_tibble, info)

## [[1]]
## [[1]]$GDP
## [1] "Gross domestic product"

## [[1]]$GNI
## [1] "Gross national income"


## [[2]]
## NULL

## [[3]]
## [[3]]$Gestalt
## [1] "theory of perception"

## [[3]]$`Affective neuroscience`
## [1] "Study of the neural mechanisms of emotion"

## [[3]]$Personality
## [1] "personality and its variation among individuals"


## [[4]]
## [[4]]$Photosynthesis
## [1] "convert light energy into chemical energy"
```

I want to do a simple textual clean-up, and `janitor::make_clean_names()` is good for the task. How can I apply `make_clean_names()` on both the names and the values in the lists under `info`, and return the same `my_tibble` (but now with clean strings)?

**Desired Output**

```r
my_tibble_cleaned <-
  tibble(
  name = c("economics", "history","psychology", "biology"),
  info = list(
    list(
      gdp = "gross_domestic_product",
      gdp = "gross_national_income"
    ),
    NULL,
    list(
      gestalt = "theory_of_perception",
      affective_neuroscience = "study_of_the_neural_mechanisms_of_emotion",
      personality = "personality_and_its_variation_among_individuals"
    ),
    list(photosynthesis = "convert_light_energy_into_chemical_energy")
  )
)
```

**Desired method**
In the parallel universe of data frames, I would do something like that:

```r
my_df <-
  data.frame(name = c("economics", "psychology", "biology"),
             info = c("GDP", "Affective neuroscience", "Photosynthesis"))

my_df %>%
  mutate(across(info, janitor::make_clean_names))
```

This `dplyr` code is just to demonstrate the simplicity I'm looking for. Can we have such succinct code for in-place modification of structures nested inside a tibble? I assume `purrr::map()` should be handy, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clean up names and values separately and combine them together.

```
library(janitor)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

result <- my_tibble %>%
            mutate(info = map(info, ~setNames(map(.x, make_clean_names), 
                                             make_clean_names(names(.x)))))
```

This returns output as :

```
result$info

#[[1]]
#[[1]]$gdp
#[1] "gross_domestic_product"

#[[1]]$gni
#[1] "gross_national_income"


#[[2]]
#named list()

#[[3]]
#[[3]]$gestalt
#[1] "theory_of_perception"

#[[3]]$affective_neuroscience
#[1] "study_of_the_neural_mechanisms_of_emotion"

#[[3]]$personality
#[1] "personality_and_its_variation_among_individuals"


#[[4]]
#[[4]]$photosynthesis
#[1] "convert_light_energy_into_chemical_energy"
```

Comment: Thanks! From this I understand that `mutate(across(...))` is not supposed to work here. Right? I'm just trying to think of the scalability of this. What if I had wanted to apply such solution over many list-columns that nest named lists?

Comment: `across` is used to apply a function to multiple columns. Here we have only 1 column (`info`) so across is not needed. If you need to apply this to multiple columns in that case you can use `across`.

Comment: I see. Then I should've provided several list-columns in my data example. Anyways, I've adapted your solution to what I had in mind when posting the question: `my_tibble %>% mutate(across(info, ~ map(., ~ setNames(map(.x, make_clean_names), make_clean_names(names(.x))))))`

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(janitor)
my_tibble %>%
           mutate(info = map(info, ~set_names(map(.x, make_clean_names), 
                                         make_clean_names(names(.x)))))
```